# I am having this issue ->Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:26.1.0

Tags: flutter

i have been trying to fix the issue below but could not find any solutions.
Does any have any ideas to fix the issue?

the error message is

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:26.1.0.
> >Required by:
> >project :app

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependencies for the artifacts you need in the build.gradle file for your app or module:

```
dependencies {
    val appcompat_version = "1.3.1"

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version")
    // For loading and tinting drawables on older versions of the platform
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version")
}
```

Comment: For more details follow this link:https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#groovy

Comment: Thank your for your help, but i am still having the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly downgraded material app from 1.7.0 to 1.6:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
}
```